# Multiple types in a SaveFileDialog filter

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog

In my SaveFileDialog I have multiple types in the filter, however when viewing the dialog if I choose a filter to view files of that type in the directory I am only able to see files for the first and last filters.

```
    bool save;
    SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = "*";
    dlg.DefaultExt = "bmp";
    dlg.ValidateNames = true;

    dlg.Filter = "Bitmap Image (.bmp)|*.bmp|Gif Image (.gif)|*.gif |JPEG Image (.jpeg)|*.jpeg |Png Image (.png)|*.png |Tiff Image (.tiff)|*.tiff |Wmf Image (.wmf)|*.wmf";
    save = (bool)dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (save)
    {
        SaveImage(dlg.FileName);
    }
```

I can see files of type .bmp and .wmf
If I change the order of the filters I can always only see the first and last.

Comment: Try eliminating the space after `*.gif ` and otheres. Filter is very picky.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Remove the spaces after the file type:

```
dlg.Filter = "Bitmap Image (.bmp)|*.bmp|Gif Image (.gif)|*.gif|JPEG Image (.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Png Image (.png)|*.png|Tiff Image (.tiff)|*.tiff|Wmf Image (.wmf)|*.wmf";
```

Comment: good illustration

Answer (score 2):

[`FilterIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filterindex?view=netframework-4.7.2) ... DefaultExt is used just during a save.
An index is 1-based so if you want to choose the 2nd option then:

```
dlg.FilterIndex = 2;
```